# Is it possible to configure read count from Statistics module?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using Blogs in my website, so I want to display the read count of each blog when user viewed the blog. For this I used core module called Statistics. But my requirement is differ from this available feature of Statistics module.

I want to Pre-set the read counter, So that I can manually enter the number of read counter. For example if I enter 100, next count should start 100 onward like 101,102... So how can I achieve this, Please suggest any module or programmatic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a count field to your blog content type, ban access of editing or creating this field using [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for other users (they just can read) now you can set its starting value.

Then using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you can create an action in a way that with each viewing of blog posts this fields value increase by one.

Comment: Thanks, it looks theoretically easy but i am not getting how to increase the field value by using views. There is no such action.

Comment: Rules actually not views, there are several tutorials on net about how to modify variables using rules module